# Confirmation about approach to take to update information about an object - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-update

I have a puzzle game with levels. Each level is binary serialized once it is created and then loaded from a .dat file. I would like to save some information about a level when the user completes it. I would like it to have information about if it is solved yet and an int variable of how many turns the user took to solve it. I cannot delete the original .dat file of the level and then re-serialize it with the int variable "turnsTaken", because the starting positions of the characters will get messed up.

Can I have an SQL database with a table of Level names and solved values, as well as lowest Turns taken to solve each level? Then upon completion of a level, update those properties of the table? Then display them in my program?

This is really just a yes or no question, to get confirmation about if I should take this approach before i spend hours trying it. If no, then please explain a better approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can save binary data to sql by storing it as type varbinary (a sql datatype).

Comment: Thanks. One last confirmation before I continue. If the database server is localhost, this means the database will be on any client machine running my game? It will be included in the game? So they will all have access to the database?

Comment: well they would need to have a database server installed on the client machine. To be honest you might be better off just saving the data to some files on the disk if thats the case.

Comment: Thanks. I think SQLite is the way to go. For saving a file to the disk, I guess you could make a level class with name, solvedStatus, and turnsTaken properties. Then foreach (level in levels) write to file: name, solvedStatus, turns taken \n. It proabably gets a little bit complex retrieving and altering the file though.